# Probability of one bin having exactly k coins, given the other has exactly n coins.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A person puts some coins in 2 bins at random, and stops when one of the bins has n coins in it. What's the probability of the other having exactly k coins?

My work:
$$P(k|n) = \frac{P(n|k)*P(k)}{P(n)}=\frac{1*P(k)}{1}$$

So probability of $P(k|n)=P(k)=0.5^{n-k}$

I am not sure I got the P(n) correct, as well as P(k), but I think P(n|k) is indeed 1, since there are always n coins in one of the bins.

Comment: So there are 2 bins in total?

Comment: Suppose $n=1, k=0$. Then we know that the answer is $1$ since the player stops after the first coin is added.  But your formula gives $.5$

Comment: Note:  this is a variant of [Banach's matchbox problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_matchbox_problem)

Comment: @IraeVid yes, sorry, corrected the question

Comment: Using notation like $P(k)$ and $P(n)$ is a great way to confuse yourself. If you distinguish the bins and write something like $P(B_2=k|B_1=n) = \frac{P(B_1=n|B_2=k) P(B_2=k)}{P(B_1=n)}$, then it will be clear to you that $P(B_1=n)$ is not $1$, for example: it is not a guarantee that $B_1$ will always be the bin with $n$ coins.

Comment: @lulu my other guess was $0.5^{k}$, which i got by setting $P(B2=k|B1=n)=P(B1=n)=(0.5)^n$

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks, that is more clear! I have updated my thinking, which still seems wrong though.

Comment: Again, I suggest studying the matchbox problem.  They aren't identical, but they are very, very close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of coins in the other bin. The probability that you are looking for.

$$P[X=k] = \binom{n+k-1}{k} \frac1{2^{n+k-1}}$$

Explanation: you need to choose the $k$ times that you put a coin in the other bin from the $n+k-1$ possibilities.

Comment: Additionally, this is for $k\in\{0,\ldots, n-1\}$

Comment: Yes of course. Otherwise the *other bin* is not defined correctly

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense